# Laravel model insert - reduce code size

Tags: php, laravel

I know it is literally going to do nothing in terms of efficiency, but is there a simple way to condense this;

```
$customer = new Customer;
$customer->firstname = $data['f_name'];
$customer->lastname = $data['l_name'];
$customer->email = $data['email'];
$customer->phone_number = $data['phone'];
$customer->venue_id = Auth::user()->venue_id;
$customer->save();
```

Into just one line of code?

My models are getting real fat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may alternatively use `create()` method but not a big difference, for example:

```
$customer = Customer::create(array(
    'firstname' => $data['f_name'],
    'lastname' => $data['l_name'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'phone_number' => $data['phone'],
    'venue_id' => Auth::user()->venue_id
));
```

To do this, you have to assign in your `Customer` model either

```
protected $fillable = array('firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'phone_number', 'venue_id')
```

Or you may use opposite one

```
// Assumed you have an id and password field
protected $guarded = array('id', 'password');
```

Or you may use a blank to allow all fields

```
protected $guarded = array();
```

So, you may use mass assignment using `create()` method of your model. Since you have a `$data` array already available with populated inputs but field names are not matched with database table, so, if you can populate the `$data` variable using proper database field names then you may use that `$data` variable in the `create()` method.

Also, you may directly use `Input` something like this:

```
$inputs = Input::except('_token'); // all inputs without _token hidden field
```

Validate these inputs then insert like:

```
Customer::create($inputs);
```

Or you may delete any item from the array using `unset($inputs['key'])` if you have other values in `$_post` array and want to remove those fields before `inserting/creating` into database table. Read about [Mass Assignment](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment).

Answer (score 1):

Use the fillable array as sheika suggested and ensure your input params match the models attributes. This is what it typically looks for me.

```
$model = Customer::create( Input::get() );
```

Or

```
$model = new Customer;
$model->fill( Input::get() );
$model->save();
```